# What causes Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, circular-dependency

**Hi**

I got this error in my layout, looks like there is no problems, but this appears when trying to open the layout in Test device:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1704)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:382)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:390)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17951)
at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1269)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:338)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17951) .......
```

**Here is my XML: [Click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-L9-45kg_JCS3N3Wk40MzBLVmc/view?usp=sharing)**

What causes the "`Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout`"-problem?

Comment: XML is not accessible. Make it a public file.

Comment: Ask for permission

Comment: lol. why should I disclose my email when you don't want to make it public and still requires help!

Comment: Ok wait ill mkae it public

Comment: your relative layout cannot accessible to circular dependancy. check your layout , you can not define two layout above and below each other

Comment: I know what you mean but check my code, I modified my code on my Android project and there is no things like you mentioned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code in your layout caused the circular dependencies,

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Weight"
            android:id="@+id/weig"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/weightn"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="46"
            android:id="@+id/weightn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/weig"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/weig"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

**Cause:**

**First Text View(weig) :** android:layout_above="@+id/weightn"

**Second Text View(weightn) :** android:layout_below="@+id/weig"

Answer (score 1):

> Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

The problem is caused when there is a circular reference in the layout parameters.

For example, you have a button A layout_below to button B, now you can not give any alignment references of button A to button B like button B align_right to button A.

Comment: Did you check my Document file?

Comment: Bacause it looks like there is no problems for your given solution

Comment: Could you check it now

Comment: Its public now to watch